# Arithmetic calculation in shell scripting-bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have an input notepad file as shown below:

sample input file:

vegetables and rates

```
kg  rate    total 
Tomato  4   50  100
potato  2   60  120 
Beans   3   80  240
```

**Overalltotal: (100+120++240) = 460**

I need to multiply the column 2 and column 3 and check the total if it is right and the overall total as well. If that's not right we need to print in the same file as an error message as shown below

enter code here

sample output file:

vegetables and rates

```
kg  rate    vegtotal

Tomato  4   50  200
potato  2   60  120 
Beans   3   80  240
```

**Overalltotal: (200+120++240) = 560**

Error in calculations: 
Vegtotal for tomato is wrong: It should be 200 instead of 100
Overalltotal is wrong: It should be 560 instead of 460

Code so far:

```
for f in Date*.log; do
       awk 'NR>1{ a[$1]=$2*$3 }{ print }END{ printf("\n");
            for(i in a)
       { if(a[i]!=$4)
              { print i,"Error in calculations",a[i] }
            } }' "$f" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$f"; 

done
```

It calculates the total but not comparing the values. How can I compare them and print to same file?

Comment: There was an almost identical question to this posted a few days ago but using student scores. Search the archives.

Answer (score 1):

Complex ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NF && NR>1 && $0!~/total:/{ 
         r=$2*$3; v=(v!="")? v"+"r : r; 
         if(r!=$4){ veg_er[$1]=r" instead of "$4 } 
         err_t+=$4; t+=r; $4=r 
     }
     $0~/total/ && err_t { 
         print $1,"("v")",$3,t; print "Error in calculations:"; 
         for(i in veg_er) { print "Veg total for "i" is wrong: it should be "veg_er[i] } 
         print "Overalltotal is wrong: It should be "t" instead of "err_t; next 
     }1' inputfile
```

The output:

```
kg  rate    total 
Tomato 4 50 200
potato 2 60 120
Beans 3 80 240

Overalltotal: (200+120+240) = 560
Error in calculations:
Veg total for Tomato is wrong: it should be 200 instead of 100
Overalltotal is wrong: It should be 560 instead of 460
```

---

Details:

- `NF && NR>1 && $0!~/total:/` - considering *veg* lines (excuding *header* and *total* lines)
- `r=$2*$3` - the result of *product* of the 2nd and 3rd fields
- `v=(v!="")? v"+"r : r` - concatenating resulting *product* values
- `veg_er` - the array containing erroneous vegs info (*veg* name, erroneous product value, and *real* product value)
- `err_t+=$4` - accumulating erroneous total value
- `t+=r` - accumulating *real* total value
- `$0~/total/ && err_t` - processing *total* line and error events

Comment: Thank you. But, the error is not writing to the file and giving it in the terminal itself. We can write error to a file by giving "}1' inputfile> output_filename" in the last line of the above mentioned code. Suppose there are multiple input files and output error should be written to each file then how do we do it?

Comment: @Rashmirao, to overwrite the initial file apply that approach from your question: `awk... inputfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile inputfile `

Comment: yeah, I did that. If I use that, it will overwrite my input file data and user needs to again open the input file to see. For this reason, I am trying to retain the input and then below that trying to display the output message.

Comment: @Rashmirao, to print the output to stdout and to the file simultaneously - use `tee` command : `awk... inputfile | tee tmpfile && mv tmpfile inputfile`

Comment: Suppose we just need the date and error of calculations to be printed on the separate file say error log, how do we do it? where to end the loop, because below code keeps looping and gives the wrong message

Comment: for f in *.log; do  
awk 'NF && NR>1 && $0!~/total:/
    {
     things_cost=$2*$3; 
     overalltotal=(overalltotal!="")? overalltotal"+"things_cost : things_cost; if(things_cost!=$4){ things_er[$1]=things_cost" instead of "$4 }
         err_t+=$4; t+=things_cost;
     }
     $0~/total/ && err_t 
     { 
     print "Error in calculations:"; 
         for(i in things_er) 
         { print "Things total for "i" is wrong: it should be "things_er[i]  } 
         print "Overalltotal is wrong: It should be "t; next 
     }1' Input_Sample_BK > error_log
 done

Comment: @Rashmirao, that's new condition, it was not mentioned in the initial question.

Comment: yes, i was trying to learn different ways of re-directing the error messages

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat file
kg  rate    total
Tomato 4 50 100 
potato 2 60 120 
Beans 3 80 240
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk 'FNR>1{sum+= $2 * $3 }1;END{print "Total : "sum}' file
kg  rate    total
Tomato 4 50 100 
potato 2 60 120 
Beans 3 80 240
Total : 560
```

**Explanation**

```
awk '                              # call awk
    FNR>1{                         # if no of lines of current file is greater than 1, 
                                   # then , this is to skip first row
            sum+= $2 * $3          # sum total which is product of value
                                   # in column2 and column3
     }1;                           # 1 at the end does default operation, 
                                   # that is print current record ( print $0 )
                                   # if you want to skip record being printed remove "1", so that script just prints total
     END{                          # end block
            print "Total : "sum    # print sum
     }
    ' file
```