# Save each day’s data (date wise) in a separate file and compare the total of that file

Tags: bash, awk

The program takes an input file as an argument. The file contains data for the whole month. It contains each day’s selling data clearly separated by a dashed line.

The program should save each day’s data (date wise) in a separate file.
I wrote a code which takes all content.

It stores content wise with different log file, but I needed date wise store to different log file. How can i do this ? Any suggestion ?

```
awk -F' ' '{filename=$1".log";print>filename;close(filename)}' input_file
```

This is input file:

```
Date: 01-01-2007
CPU      3    7098    22394
Monitor  2    6500    13000
Mouse    20   300     6000
Total: 41394
---------------------------------------------------
Date: 04-01-2007
Keyboard         10    700    7000
Ethernet-Card    48    900    43200
Total: 50020
---------------------------------------------------
<again some data here …>
```

And Also, the data must be reconciled (compared) to see whether all calculations are fine and no data has been tampered, i.e. it should total again by adding individual item prices present in the file. When the total does not match, it should write an error message in the log file clearly stating which day’s data had the problem.
 This is my code as shown below:
awk 'NF && NR>1 && $0!~/total:/{ r=$2*$3; v=(v!="")? v"+"r : r;if(r!=$4){ things_er[$1]=r" instead of "$4 } err_t+=$4; t+=r; $4=r }
But it is not printing error message and also not sure its comparing the total properly.

Comment: it remains to you to post the input file fragment

Comment: This is input file:                                                                                                              Date: 01-01-2007
CPU     3    7098    22394
Monitor  2    6500    13000
Mouse    20   300     6000
Total: 41394
---------------------------------------------------
Date: 04-01-2007
Keyboard      10    700    7000
Ethernet-Card    48    900    43200
Total: 50020
---------------------------------------------------
<again some data here …>

Comment: not in comments - move it to the question and apply formatting

Comment: This is the 3rd almost identical question recently from 3 different users. The first was about student data, [the second was about vegetables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44600613/1745001) and now this one about computer hardware. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution to store each `Date` section to different file:

```
awk '/^Date:/{ fn=$2".log" }!/--/{ print > fn }' input_file
```

- `/^Date:/{ fn=$2".log" }` - on encountering `Date` pattern line - build filename `fn` in form e.g. `01-01-2007.log`
- `!/--/` - skip "*dash*" lines

---

Results (for 2 dates):

```
> cat 01-01-2007.log 
Date: 01-01-2007
CPU      3    7098    22394
Monitor  2    6500    13000
Mouse    20   300     6000
Total: 41394
```

---

```
> cat 04-01-2007.log 
Date: 04-01-2007
Keyboard         10    700    7000
Ethernet-Card    48    900    43200
Total: 50020
```